# Find my IP address when ssh'ing when behing a web proxy

Tags: networking, ssh

I'm on a corporate network and need to find out the external IP address that my ssh is showing up as so I can white-list it.

I can't use whatismyip.com or "curl ifconfig.me" because this network is proxying all the web traffic, so the IP is different than what SSH goes out as.

Is there an equivalent service that I can SSH to and it will repeat my external IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally got around to solving this myself:

http://ipcheck.finne.us/

Chrome won't do a request on port 22, so

```
curl http://ipcheck.finne.us:22/
```